# Electron - TypeError: core.require is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am just trying out electron and have a very simple app that should load a webpage when running `npm start`

```
var app = require('app');
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

app.on('ready', function() {

    var window = new BrowserWindow({

        height : 750,
        width: 1000,
        frame: false

    });

    window.loadUrl('https://google.com');
});
```

But I get the error : `TypeError: core.require is not a function`

The commands I run are:

1. `npm install electron-prebuilt`
2. `npm install app`
3. `npm install browser-window`

My package.json is:

```
{
    "name": "SimpleWeb",
    "version" : "0.0.2",
    "main" : "main.js",
    "scripts" : {
        "start" : "electron ."
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting the crash - could someone help me out here :-)

**UPDATE WAS USING OLD CODE :-(**

Replace the top 2 lines, with these 3.

```
var electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
```

Comment: `npm install app` <- Are you sure you wanted this module? You sure you don't want `var app = require('electron').app`?

Comment: I have followed a few tutorials, but was trying to replicate this demo
https://youtu.be/Xs3Oc4weZbw?t=976 - this uses `require('app')`

Comment: `require('app')` will attempt to use [this](http://npmjs.org/package/app) module which is 6 years old and I literally have no idea what it does and it isn't related to Electron in any way. Try replacing it with my previous suggestion and post back.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that when browsing other forums as I kept working on it. It works now.
I also changed the top lines - so I will put that result in the question

Comment: Also do the same for the BrowserWindow. If you are leveraging newer ES syntax, you can do both in one line `var { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')`

Comment: make an answer out of it and score some points :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron now contains all of it's 'parts' within the root Electron package. As such, you don't need the `browser-window` or `app` packages (I am not even sure what they are/do).

You can import the relevant parts straight out of the core electron package.

```
// One Line
var { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
// OR
// Three Lines
var electron = require('electron')
var app = electron.app
var BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
```

Both approaches are valid. From there, everything else should be fine.